Unable to resolve dependency tree error while trying to update langchain npm packages
I am trying to update langchain packages, my packages are as followed:

langchain
@langchain/community
langfuse-langchain
@langchain/openai
@langchain/google-genai
@google/generative-ai
I can't update the package and I keep getting this error:

`npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: langchain@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: puppeteer@22.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/puppeteer
npm ERR!   peerOptional puppeteer@"^22.0.0" from @langchain/community@0.2.21
npm ERR!   node_modules/@langchain/community
npm ERR!     @langchain/community@"^0.2.21" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @langchain/community@"*" from langchain@0.2.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/langchain
npm ERR!       langchain@"^0.2.11" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (langfuse-langchain, @langchain/community, @getzep/zep-cloud)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional puppeteer@"^19.7.2" from langchain@0.2.11
npm ERR! node_modules/langchain
npm ERR!   langchain@"^0.2.11" from the root project
npm ERR!   node_modules/langfuse-langchain
npm ERR!     langfuse-langchain@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (@langchain/community, @getzep/zep-cloud)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.`

From the message, I think it's because of puppeteer conflict, so I tried uninstalling every single one of the packages and re-install them, I found out that the 3 packages that cause problems are:

langchain
@langchain/community
langfuse-langchain

I found some solutions:

Posted in here https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchainjs/issues/5673 is to use --legacy-peer-deps while installing said 3 packages. It works but I don't think it is a good solution. Is --legacy-peer-deps the only workaround?
Another solution by NPM Err: Unable to resolve dependencies is to completely wipe node_modules and package-lock.json but again I was advise not to touch package-lock.json.


From today even I am getting the same issue.
